# Problem logging users out

Tags: php

I use the following codes to log users out from a web app. while logging in I set cookie email and password, but after logging out, visiting the home page automatically logs the user in again, probably because the cookie wasn't successfully destroyed. Please how do I get it right. Here is log out code

```
function log_out() {
   $old_user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];
   unset($_SESSION['valid_user']);
   unset($_SESSION['login']);
   unset($_SESSION['blog_addr']);
   $result_dest = session_destroy();

   setcookie('email', '');
   setcookie('pswd', '');

   if (!empty($old_user)) 
     if ($result_dest)
       return true;
     else 
       $msg = 'Could not log you out ';
   else 
        $msg = 'You have not been logged in so you are not logged out ';      
   return $msg;
}///:~
```

Comment: Please do not store people's passwords in their cookies. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410901/what-should-be-stored-in-a-cookie-for-a-login-system for better ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: from a security perspective, it's a really bad idea to store the password in a cookie.  you may want to read over the two strategies here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html. (even though the docs are for a java package the principles are still very applicable!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set setcookie to an expiration date in the past. See the example here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the cookie expiration for some time in the past:

`setcookie ("email", "", time() - 3600);`

Answer (score 1):

How did you set up your cookie? ( logging in ).

In general setting a cookie off , you have to go back in time !

```
setcookie("email", "",time()-3600,'/');
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other comments. You've set $_SESSION['valid_user']; to $old_user before you did an unset, so you should't be checking for $old_user as it contains the old data. you should't even need to set those to any variables. Also you should be using brackets.

```
function log_out() {
   unset($_SESSION['valid_user']);
   unset($_SESSION['login']);
   unset($_SESSION['blog_addr']);
   session_destroy();

   setcookie('email', '', time() - 3600);
   setcookie('pswd', '', time() - 3600);

   if (!isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])){
     if ($result_dest) // don't know what this does.
       return true;
     else 
       $msg = 'Could not log you out ';
   }
   else
        $msg = 'You have not been logged in so you are not logged out ';      
   return $msg;
}
```

Comment: I think the session_destroy() function returns a bool, so the line if($result_dest) checks if the session was successfully destroyed. although I don't really see need for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the cookies by doing this:

```
setcookie ("email", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ("pswd", "", time() - 3600);
```

This will delete the cookies by setting their expiration date in the past.